# validate int which exceeds PHP_INT_MAX value (2147483647) in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation, int

Any workaround to validate an int field which exceeds PHP_INT_MAX (2147483647 on 32 bit) value? The code I am using in Zend framework is:

```
'int_input' => array(
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'Zend_Validate_Int',
        array('Zend_Validate_Between',0,4000000000),
        'message' => 'Int must be between 1 and 4,000,000,000.'
    )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically no, because it's not a PHP Integer if it's out of bounds.

But you can use `Zend_Validate_Digits` with `Zend_Validate_Between` to make sure the passed value is a number in a specific range though.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that's exactly what I was looking for. The 'Zend_Validate_Digit' should be 'Zend_Validate_Digits'?